# Creating an extension methods results in an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to create an HTML helper methos for and asp.net MVC project but I must be doing something wrong because when I try to call the method I get this error:

> Error 1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   does not contain a definition for 'LabelSomething' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'TestProject.Modules.Pager.LabelSomething(System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper,
>   string, string)' has some invalid
>   arguments d:\Training\Practis.Internship.Workspace\Alex.Nistor\ADO.NET\TestProject\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    35  6   ADO.NET
>
> Error 2   Instance argument: cannot convert from
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' to
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' d:\Training\Practis.Internship.Workspace\Alex.Nistor\ADO.NET\TestProject\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    35  6   ADO.NET

This is my code:

```
public static class Pager
{
    public static string LabelSomething(this HtmlHelper helper, string target , string text){
        return string.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);
    }
}
```

This is how I tryed to call it:

```
 @Html.LabelSomething("fsaf" , "ddada")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in which namespace your class is?

Comment: if the namespace is outside, you should import your namespace in your web.config inside views folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying the `HtmlHelper` from  MVC, instead it is currently pointing to `WebPages.Html` Modify your extension method as:

```
public static class Pager
{
    public static string LabelSomething(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper helper, string target , string text){
        return string.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And you can putting your helpers in App_Code works but has certain limitations that impact certain MVC scenarios (for example: no access to standard MVC Html. helpers)